# Does God solve the problem of objective morality?

Tags: theology

I’ve seen people talk about how if there’s no God, there is no source for your morality and that it would be based on your whims. It’s a pretty common way of thinking especially among theists.

But wouldn’t God just be another agent? I understand that He is defined to be good in some religions, but can’t any agent be defined to be good? What makes what He says better than what I say or what my friend says.

If the argument is that He knows better because He created everyone, how does that work? Can’t the creator be evil?

Comment: If God's rules are followed to avoid damnation, this may imply a type of [consequentialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consequentialism). If this were so, then God's character may be somewhat irrelevant. The question, however, of objective morality could still arise, as one could then ask, *why did one choose consequentialism?*

Comment: The idea goes back to [Dostoevsky](https://owaprod-pub.wesleyan.edu/reg/!wesmaps_page.html?stuid=&crse=013760&term=1169):"*If there is no God, then everything is permitted*". It is questionable and has been criticized. But, at least in monotheistic religions, God is not "just another agent", he is all-knowing, all-powerful, all-good, etc.  Still, whether God's will establishes objective morality is controversial, see the [Euthyphro dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euthyphro_dilemma):"*Is it good and just because God wills it or God wills it because it is good and just*".

Answer (score 1):

No definition was provided for God. And thus far no answer was given here for an *impersonal* perspective. Since this view is held in quite a few schools, it would be incomplete to exclude.

If God were defined impersonally, as say *everything,* then God's nature would by default align with human nature since humans would be an extension *of* God. Here, any moral system which aligned with human nature would thus be part of God's nature -- and hence follow God's will.

As it turns out, human's nature is to follow *human values.* These, further, develop through instrumental progression based on experience and inference. I discuss this more in-depth in a post [on the nature of personal values](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90639/what-are-personal-values-more-exactly/90652#90652). Technically, even *with* the belief in God, one's morality is based on personal values, or "whims". These values have simply incorporated external instrumental elements through the experience of religion and faith.

Such God would indeed solve the problem of objective morality, as our intrinsic nature -- along with all its instruments -- would serve God *implicitly.* There would in fact be no way to *avoid* fulfilling God's will.

Comment: Or one could that what is good is what serves the natural growth of the species. I think I've seen that somewhere...

Comment: @Frank -- In practice, culturally propagated moral systems tend to reflect mature, long-term inference and speculation about the cause and effect of human actions. Sometimes these are based on mere assumptions. Other times these are situation-specific.

There is a natural progression of moral scope that occurs during individual development. I briefly describe this in *Part 1* of [this answer](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90220/is-winning-competition-inherently-unethical/90225#90225). There may be a point where one's species is the scope. But later one may expand the circle.

Comment: @Frank -- With that said, obviously different people are going to have different idiosyncratic values from personal proclivities and experience. Certain instrumental paths may appear suiting of one's intrinsic desires. As mentioned, these may be based on speculation. And sometimes that speculation is misguided. This is part of the natural trial-and-error of learning. To say we should avoid "thinking for ourselves", instead sticking to old traditions, may avoid suffering shorter-term, but without the pain of progress, we may never move forward. Hindsight is 20/20.

Comment: I was trying to make a reference to Nietzsche :-)

Comment: @Frank -- I see. In general I agree that bigger scopes are better, and serving the species is almost always better than serving only an individual or small group. Nietzsche was certainly trying to make things better, to the best of his knowledge. There is no doubt merit in personal improvement; although it would be imbalanced to forget or deny the larger system and culture's influences on personal success.

Comment: Nietzsche seems to think very little of the ambient (christian, socialist, ...) culture he was immersed in, but seemed to be influenced by ideas about evolution, with a heavy dose of longing for Homeric times where strong heroes defined morality and imposed it to the weak. It seemed like an interesting, albeit extreme maybe, counterpoint in this discussion :-)

Comment: @Frank -- I agree that ruthless individual competition versus its proposed societal benefit seems something of a paradox. Sometimes higher modes of moral reasoning can look to bend back onto themselves. Another notable example is that when a group or individual moves past rules-based ethics (stage 4) onto the social contract (stage 5), it can appear as if the prior progress of tradition or composure has been disregarded. Yet it was retired to facilitate individual or group self-determination, not for lawlessness. For its appearance, holdouts sometimes present proposed progress as regression.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we delve into theism/antitheism kerfuffles we should take great care to avoid the straw-man arguments that get flung around incessantly. In this case it's the straw-man of overly-anthropomorphized gods...

In theistic religion gods are only anthropomorphized (properly speaking) to emphasize that the relationship between man and god is a *social* one. A god is an idealization of wise, far-seeing leader: one who sees things we cannot, who guides us away from unknown pitfalls and towards unforeseen good. It's the Great Shepard image from Psalm 23: "Yea, though I walk through the valley of the shadow of death, I will fear no evil: for thou art with me; thy rod and thy staff they comfort me." Gods are not typically considered 'moral agents' because they are intrinsically moral; they never have to make moral *choices* the way that men (in their limited vision) do. As such, a god can represent a source or moral wisdom because men who choose to follow god — who develop a proper and affirmative social relationship with god — will behave more morally.

Non-theistic approaches vest morality in different sources, such as idealizations of human virtue, deontological rules, reasoning about consequences, etc., but largely that's just a shift from one transcendent source to another. Asking why a god can't be evil is a bit like asking why a universal rule of ethics can't be stupid. There's no reason for it except that we would reject such a thing out of hand.

Comment: Your last two sentences are clearly not true.  Yahweh orders a lot of evil, the Mesopotamian gods set up a pretty evil world per those religions, and the Greek gods could be petty, spiteful and arguably evil.  And some stupid ethics have been articulated and argued. So -- we humans have followed evil Gods, and held by stupid ethics.

Comment: @Dcleve: Sometimes a shepherd kills a wolf; that doesn't make the shepherd 'evil', though that may be hard for the sheep to understand. Let's leave the Greek pantheon out of it (because they were meant to anthropomorphize human mental states). A monolithic god that is defined to be good (the source of moral orientation) is *ipso facto* good (and thus not a moral agent), and if humans misinterpret the nature of its acts, that's a human issue.

Comment: @Dcleve: Monotheistic contexts don't question whether God's acts are good; God's acts are what they are, and followers question why an intrinsically good act might appear evil to human eyes. I'm not advocating for that perspective, mind you; that's just the nature of the religious phenomenon.

Comment: Ted, anyone who says that God is Good, or that God is NOT "good as we know it", or any of the other multiple ways to claim a moral aspect to God, IS implicitly "questioning whether God's acts are good".  The inter-religious debates over the morality of each other's sacred scripture, are explicit applications of "questioning whether God's actions are good".  This activity is a central aspect of theologizing, and the logical potential for a God not to be good is explicit in Lucifer, Ahriman, the demiurge in Marcionism, and Cthulhu

Comment: *"A god is an idealization of wise, far-seeing leader"* This sounds like saying that a god is a metaphor for goodness, rather than a literal entity.

Comment: @Sandejo: I sometimes put things badly in these discussions; I'm not a theist, so my language isn't always canon. It might be better to say that a monotheistic god is a platonic ideal: extant, but not manifested. The strict dichotomy your trying to make strikes me as unfair.

Comment: @Dcleve: Understandings of god are deeply affected by an individual's developmental level. Please don't assume that the least developed practitioners of a faith are in fact the epitome of the faith. Otherwise you run smack into the 'American Problem', where we all start assuming that Liberty means acting like a middle-schooler.  Religious people who question scripture are not questioning god, they are questioning a different faith's interpretation of god.

Comment: @Dcleve: Further, invoking Lucifer, Ahriman, the demiurge, or Cthulhu isn't going to help your case, and we can see why in simple human terms. If we credit democracy as being 'good' (a virtuous ideal), then we have to realize that democracy breeds fascism, because democracy cannot crush fascism without simultaneously destroying that which makes it good. And yes, even fascists believe they are acting 'for the good', even it's a corrupted vision. Lucifer (light-bringer) would I imagine style himself a liberator, not a rebel, and even Cthulhu is a hero in his own story (if not in Lovecraft's)

Comment: @TedWrigley -- Relative to a God who could be evil -- your reference to human rationalizations is only partially useful.  Humans can be evil, but only intermittently so.   We all have mixed motives.  We ALSO do a lot of rationalizing of our motives, so that we are always a "hero in our own story".  However, a moral transformation IS a thing among us humans, where those who have done evil, and rationalized it, experience regret and guilt.  So even thru the rationalizations, we can know that we are NOT always "the hero".

Comment: @TedWrigley Deities are generally assumed to have better self-monitoring of their motives than we do -- anthropomorphizing a unique human weakness onto Gods as if it were a necessity, strikes me at least as an implausible leap.  HUMANS however, in constructing their religions, DO extend this rationalizing to it.  The defenses of how clearly falsified scripture is somehow infallible, and how an evil action (torture for eternity) is somehow forced upon a God by us mere humans, is very energetic rationalizing, and it is motivated by extending truth and morality tests to dogma and failing them.

Comment: @Dcleve: It seems to me you've missed the point I was making with that 'democracy' analogy. I wasn't precisely talking about human beings (or their frailties or limitations). I was talking about the nature of the ideal. Ideal democracy *necessarily* entails the possibility of fascism, because democracy must entertain all views (even anti-democratic views) or it isn't democracy. Ideal goodness *necessarily* entails the possibility of evil, because if it cannot accept evil it isn't truly good. These are not decisions a god makes; these are conditions of godhood.

Comment: @Dcleve: humans rationalize, sometimes to their own chagrin. Gods do not suffer that problem.

Answer (score 0):

[The Euthyphro Dilemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euthyphro_dilemma) raises the same issue. What you ask of us (is good *whatever the hell* we *wish* it to be?) can be asked of God too (is good *whatever the hell* God *wishes* it to be?).

The problem as you can see has been "solved" by merely kicking the  can down the road and now the can is again next to our feet.

That said, an attribute of God is *omnibenevolence* which, ignoring *omnipotence*, makes it *impossible* for God to *command evil*. To get right to the point, even God's whims and fancies will be good ... *objectively*.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**

No.  If a creator God exists, that God's commands or intentions are not the "definition" of good.  This is the basis for the Euthyphro dialog of Socrates. Power =/= morality.

**Longer answer**

One of the more effective critiques of religious thinking is to apply moral tests to the claimed character and actions of a God, to see if they comport with that God being "All Good".  The most famous of these tests is the Problem of Evil, but there are multitudes of other such tests that one can do on more specific claims and behaviors that religions make.

Earlier generations of atheists often conceded that being religious led to moral behavior, but the New Atheist movement from around the turn of this last century did not concede this point, and emphasized moral critiques of religions.  This was explicit in a number of their book titles, such as "God is Not Great".

There are a variety of religious responses to these attacks.  One is to double down on command ethics, and assert that morality is defined as obedience to power, and our moral intuitions otherwise are simply wrong.  This runs counter to basically all other moral thinking, and also runs afoul of the Eden story where humans receive a valid divine moral intuition from the apple.  A second is to admit that God is not moral, and declare that morality does not apply to God.  This second approach is to concede that the Omni-God hypothesis is false, and give up on omni-benevolent.  The third approach is to assert that God is both creator AND good, therefore obedience and goodness have no conflict.  This third approach then must deal with the failed test cases, and will generally have to modify theology to comport with our morality (rejecting scriptural or other evidential sources), or rationalize evil behavior as "good", effectively redefining "good" and making it a meaningless independent standard, per the first option.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question could be more specific. Do you mean moral knowledge, [moral motivation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-motivation/), what exactly? If the latter

> In our everyday lives, we confront a host of moral issues. Once we
> have deliberated and formed judgments about what is right or wrong,
> good or bad, these judgments tend to have a marked hold on us.
> Although in the end, we do not always behave as we think we ought, our
> moral judgments typically motivate us, at least to some degree, to act
> in accordance with them. When philosophers talk about moral
> motivation, this is the basic phenomenon that they seek to understand... When we make the normative
> judgment that something is **good for us**, or that we have a reason to
> act in a particular way, or that a specific course of action is the
> rational course, we also tend to be moved. Many philosophers have
> regarded the motivating force of normative judgments as the key
> feature that marks them as normative, thereby distinguishing them from
> the many other judgments we make. In contrast to our normative
> judgments, our mathematical and empirical judgments, for example, seem
> to have no intrinsic connection to motivation and action.

That's in some sense the clearest relevance of theology for moral questions, at least assuming good works are rewarded by God.

---

[This](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/moral-arguments-god) article talks about different moral arguments for God. Part 3 (Theoretical Moral Arguments for God’s Existence and Divine Command Theories of Moral Obligation) talks about moral motivation. If you do not feel that God's commands can be motivating then I would think you do not believe in "God", and that's all there is to it. [Misotheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misotheism) is a word I like.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some thoughts:

First of all: which god are you referring to?
There's one god that's referred to as summum bonum, which means "only good".

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summum_bonum

In traditional jewish mythology god is king of good **and** evil.

The human capacity for evil is extraordinary like with chimps. We love violence and war, and it will remain in some form for a while. Like rape.

Kant said that if we would meet god, it would be very bad for our morals. I'm not sure why exactly, but he said it!

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_morality

Hope this helps you.